# i want to validate calender as departure and destination date and date should not be less than departure date?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<html>
  <body>
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="" id="departuredate"/>
   <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date_arrival" id="arrivaldate" value="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a code for giving date. I want to validate calender as `departure` and `destination` date. `destination` date should not be less than `departure` date

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: You want to validate it in javascript or in php

Comment: i want use javascript using id but i dont know how will put on it and alert

Comment: this code is like us booking trip

Comment: So what are you using for calendars (any library)? you can use jquery calendar

Comment: only simple type =date

Comment: no nothing, actually i want calculate date not should be less than with alert using id simple javascript code

Comment: you should use `min` and `max` attributes

Comment: how can i use this attributes

Comment: actually my site on booking trip and when somebody will book than it will show only calander

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery before this code and call the below code on form submit:

```
<script>
    var startDate = new Date($('#departuredate').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#arrivaldate').val());

    if (startDate < endDate){
    alert("date shoul be geater");
    }
    </script>
```